# Can i get Analyctics from an API or anything from the google beacon dashboard, without users having an app?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-nearby

I use googles beacon dashboard and nearby notifications to send out adverts for businesses to any android device within range of the beacon, what i want to know is if there is a way to see how many devices my adverts are hitting without the devices having to have my app. Just if there is an API or anything to pull that data from google without using a 3rd party like beaconstac or another kind of platform offering real time analytics